# Table size bigger than buffer pool size

Tags: mysql

What if table size more than buffer pool size . How data and index are cached in buffer pool size if the table size is more than buffer pool size.

For example:

One of my innodd table size is 231 gb. How data and index are cached in this table

Comment: When data size oversizes cache size, it can be cached only partially. In practice that mean the random part of data will be cached, so the caching makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Akina, is not the most recently read information cached?  So if 1% is read 99% of the time it would still make sense to have a sufficiently large bufferpool (disclaimer, I don't know much about MariaDB)

Comment: @Lennart MySQL uses LRU strategy with 3/8 insertion point and 1 page granularity. If 1% you tell above is less than 5/8 of buffer - it may be cached effectively. If it is more than 5/8, some pages may elect, decreasing effectiveness (disclaimer, I don't know much about MariaDB too).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, I meant to write MySQL (which I don't know much about either:-). For another DBMS:s I have a system with slightly less than 1Tb data+index and a bufferpool of 10Gb. The hitratio is around 99.95%, so despite that the bp is a fraction of the size of the data almost all data is found in the bp.

Comment: @user154495  If you could post complete Mysqltuner.pl report, we will have excellent clues on your systems configuration, RAM available, by ENGINE data and index sizes, number of tables and other helpful information for a quick analysis your system.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer.**  Not a problem, except for slowing down.

**Long Answer:** (InnoDB-specific)

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` controls the InnoDB "cache".  It is broken into 16KB "blocks", each of which comes and goes from RAM based, roughly, on a Least-Recently-Used algorithm.  (See "1 page granularity" mentioned in a Comment.)

So, when you fetch something from a table, the query execution probably needs to look in an index to find where to find the something, and proceeds to fetch blocks as needed to find it.  For simple queries, this is a few blocks, for a full table scan of your 231GB, it will involve fetching all the approx 14 million blocks.

When a block needs to be fetched, but the cache is full, then some block must be bumped out of the cache.  (Hence the reference to LRU.)

If the "working set" of your data is a lot smaller than 231GB, then there won't be much I/O, and the size of the cache (buffer_pool) is not critical.  But if you do table scans, or use UUIDs, then queries will still run, but they will run slower due to the I/O due to [re]loading blocks into the cache.

All operations are done in the cache; almost nothing bypasses the cache.  Indexes and Data are each stored in BTrees that are composed of 16KB blocks.